# Fine Tuning Search and Remove

Tags: c++, performance, search

My assignment for my Data Structures Class is to implement a version of Linked List that creates Words. The class is called WORD and is a linked list of characters. One of the operations required is removing one WORD from another. For example,

```
WORD t1("testing");
WORD t2("es");

t1.Remove(t2);

cout<<t1; //Outputs tting
```

and

```
WORD t1("testing");
WORD t2("t");
t1.RemoveAll(t2);
cout<<t1; //Outputs esing
```

The code for the both of these is the following:

```
//Deletes an entire word from the list
//boolean passed to delete first occurrence of that word
//or all occurrences

void WORD::Delete(WORD & B, bool deleteAll)
{
    alpha_numeric *next, *last_word_start, *prev, *currB;

    bool found = false;
    next = last_word_start = prev = this->head;
    currB = B.head;

    while(next != NULL)
    {
        if(next->symbol == currB->symbol)
        {
            next = next->next;
            currB = currB->next;
        }
        else
        {
            prev = last_word_start;
            last_word_start = last_word_start->next;
            next = last_word_start;
            currB = B.head;
        }

        if(currB == NULL)
        {
            prev->next = next;

            while(last_word_start != next)
            {
                if(last_word_start == this->head)
                {
                    this->head = last_word_start->next;
                }
                alpha_numeric *temp = last_word_start->next;
                delete last_word_start;
                last_word_start = temp;
            }

            if(!deleteAll)
                break;

            currB = B.head;
        }
    }
}
```

So my questions are :

1. What is the Run Time of this function? I believe it's Worst Case Scenario is O(n^2)
2. What can I do to make this more efficient?

I'm beginning to learn about optimizing and such. Whats the thought process when trying to optimize this? Mainly trying to get it down to nlog(n).

Comment: Didn't read your whole code, but from the description, it sounds like you're looking for something like the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)

Comment: Note: `WORD` is a predefined type on Windows

Comment: It doesn't affect my code.